# Integral over a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Imagine I want to compute the integral $\int \int y$ over the triangle defined by the points $(1,1), (2,1), (0,2)$ in the $(x,y)$ plane.

I translate this problem into

\begin{align}
I & = \int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{2-x}^{2-x/2}y dy +\int_{1}^{2}dx\int_{1}^{2-x/2}y dy \\
  & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}dx[(2-x/2)^{2}-(2-x)^{2}]+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}dx[(2-x/2)^{2}-1] \\
  & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}(2-x/2)^{2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(2-x)^{2}dx-\frac{1}{2} \\
  & = \int_{0}^{2}\left[2-x+\frac{x^{2}}{8}\right]dx-\int_{0}^{1}\left[2-2x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right]dx-\frac{1}{2} \\
  & = 4-\frac{4}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-2+1-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2} \\
  & = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

But I believe this result is wrong (should be less than 1 by a coarse approximation of the integral).

I must be doing a silly mistake or my initial setup is wrong?

P.S. Fixed it! Thanks to Joey Zou for finding the bug and to John Wayland Bales for showing a much simpler way of computing the integral.

Comment: The way you are attempting to work the problem causes me to wonder if what you meant to ask is how to find the volume of a solid bounded below by the triangle in question and above by the plane $z=y$? Was that the question that you intended?

Comment: I am trying to compute the integral of $y$ over the given triangle.

Comment: The limits in the second integral after the third equals sign should be from 0 to 1, not 1 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler to integrate wrt $y$ since this does not require breaking it up into two pieces.

\begin{align}
\int_1^2(4-2y)-(2-y)\,dy&=\int_1^22-y\,dy\\
                        &=1/2        
\end{align}

Also, somewhere your first integral from $0$ to $1$ accidentally got changed to an integral from $0$ to $2$. And you lost me with the squaring, as though you were doing a solid of revolution or something.

Now that you have edited the question I believe that your original intention was to ask how to find the volume of the solid bounded below by the given triangle in the $xy$ plane and bounded above by the graph of $z=y$ so I will add the solution to that problem as well.

\begin{align}
V=\int_1^2\int_{2-y}^{4-2y}y\,dx\,dy&=\int_1^2xy{\huge\vert}_{2-y}^{4-2y}\,dy\\
&=\int_1^22y-y^2\,dy\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: The integral is over the function $y$ not $1$. So I believe following your approach should give $\int_{1}^{2}y(2-y)dy=4-1-8/3+1/3=2/3$. I wonder why I dont get this value doing it the other way. I combined $\int_{0}^{1}dx(2-x/2)^{2}+\int_{1}{2}dx(2-x/2)^{2}=\int_{0}^{2}dx(2-x/2)^{2}$.

Comment: Well, essentially you chose a very messy approach. I tried to do it that way twice and got two different wrong answers, none of which equalled your answer.